# How much aid has the United States given Israel compared to occupied Palestine?

Tags: united-states, israel, palestine

Since Israel's declaration of the State of Israel how much aid has Israel received from the USA compared to occupied Palestine (up to the present moment)?

Comment: Without context, your question is at best misleading and at worst seems to have a malicious intent to deliberately paint USA in bad light. It's like asking "how much money did I give my best friend as a present, compared to a guy who hated me in school". Except without mentioning the "friend" and "hated" parts.

Comment: @user4012: I think it's well known that the USA has had a long term client relationship with Israel and so one expects their to be huge disparities between the aid that they have given Israel and Palestine. I'm asking how a question that quantifies this difference. Well, if the facts embarass the USA, then they have themselves only to blame.

Comment: I will vote to keep this question open if "occupied Palestine" can be more specifically defined.  I also **assume** that you mean United States Government aid as contrasted with NGO aid based in the US.

Comment: Is the question only about "occupied" Palestine, or about the self-governing territories as well?

Comment: Not every question needs context, but it feels like this question could benefit a lot because most probably the purpose is a comparison. But what is a useful comparison? Values per capita, per GDP, compared to support for other countries or from other countries? Then it would be interesting. And occupied Palestine should be clarified.

Answer (score 9):

Too many comments are assuming context. This is a simple question and there's a simple answer.

Aid to [Israel from US, according to the Congressional Research Service](http://dev.journalistsresource.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Military-Aid-to-Israel.pdf) (as of 2011 fiscal year end):

> Israel is the largest cumulative recipient of U.S. foreign assistance since World War II. To date,
> the United States has provided Israel **$115 billion in bilateral assistance**

.. aid to [Palestine from the US, again from the Congressional Research Service](https://fas.org/sgp/crs/mideast/RS22967.pdf) but a different report, as of 2015 fiscal year end:

> Until this year, the U.S. government had consistently supported economic assistance to the
> Palestinians and humanitarian contributions to the U.N. Relief and Works Agency for Palestine
> Refugees in the Near East (UNRWA), even if funding in some cases was reduced or delayed.
> **Bilateral assistance to the Palestinians since 1994 has totaled more than $5 billion**, and has been a
> key part of U.S. policy to encourage an Israeli-Palestinian peace process, improve life for West
> Bank and Gaza residents, and (since 2007) strengthen the West Bank-based PA vis-à-vis **Hamas in Gaza. U.S. contributions to UNRWA through global humanitarian accounts since 1950 have
> totaled more than $6 billion**.

So, Israel gets more. Make what you will of the narrative, but that's the data.

[This is the source](https://www.loc.gov/crsinfo/), straight from the U.S. Government:

> The Congressional Research Service (CRS) works exclusively for the United States Congress, providing policy and legal analysis to committees and Members of both the House and Senate, regardless of party affiliation. As a legislative branch agency within the Library of Congress, CRS has been a valued and respected resource on Capitol Hill for more than a century.
>
> CRS is well-known for analysis that is authoritative, confidential, objective and nonpartisan. Its highest priority is to ensure that Congress has 24/7 access to the nation’s best thinking.

Comment: Two things: if US gives money through humanitarian organizations, then The US Government (The United States) gives cotributions for the purpose of helping Palestine. Now, is this money solely US or how many more countries gives also contributions?

Comment: @nelruk The answer specifies that it is bilateral aid to the Palestinian Authority and Hamas. So the $5 billion (or $6 billion since 1950) is specifically money from the U.S. The CRS reports confirm this. Of course, you're right that other organizations around the world give additional money to Palestine (just as they do to Israel) but that's out of scope for the question.

Comment: $115 Billion is lite.   $115 billion is just budgeted Military aid.   Total Budgeted Annual US. Aid to Israel along with charitable donations stands at closer to **[$160 Billion](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/total-u-s-foreign-aid-to-israel-1949-present)**.  The U.S. News and World Report estimates total U.S. aid to Israel 1949-2023 stands at **$260 Billion**.   I'm guessing the extra $100 billion is attributed to U.S. support for Iron dome $10 Billion + and various other off budget projects the U.S. has supported over the years.

Comment: "Israel gets more" No surprise, they are larger. Per capita would be a fairer comparison.

Comment: @JMS FWIW, the US gave over $100 billion in military and other aid to Ukraine in a single year, whereas it only gave a total of $115 billion or maybe $260 billion to Israel over all those years (2023 - 1949 ~ 73 years). I am being somewhat facetious, because I wonder if U.S. News and World Report adjusted for purchasing power parity (say, in 2022 dollars). I would expect the CRS to have done so! I didn't read enough of the report to be certain...

Comment: @EllieKesselman total US military aid to Ukraine as of Dec 6 is 46 billion.  As for us Israeli aid being adjusted perhaps.  I’ll try to run that down. Thank you for the comment. To your first point though I think Biden is asking for another 50 billion which congress is balking at currently.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:**
>
> How much aid has the United States given Israel compared to occupied Palestine?

**Answer**

- **Israel:**

**[U.S. News and World reports](https://www.usnews.com/news/best-countries/articles/2023-10-10/how-much-aid-does-the-u-s-give-to-israel)** in Oct 2023 estimates "Total" U.S. Aid to Israel stands at **$260 Billion dollars**.  That's 3.5 Billion annually over Israel's 74 year existence, or currently averaging about $4 Billion a year since 2010.  And another **$120 Billion** of US aid not included in that total US aid to Israel has gone to Egypt and Jordan after each signed peace deals with Israel in 1978, and 1996 respectively.  Part of each peace agreement has included U.S. taxpayers to pay both parties.

- **Palestine:**

The **[US gives the Palestinians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_aid_to_Palestinians)** about $600 million a year or **$5.6 Billion since 1994**.

**Addendum on Israeli Peace Agreements:**

The US pays Egypt $2.1 Billion a year and has since 1978 when Egypt signed a peace treaty with Israel. Prior to the peace treaty Egypt did not receive annual aid from the United States. Since the Peace treaty Egypt is the second largest recipient to U.S aid second only to Israel. The U.S. payments to Egypt were part of the peace agreement. So that's another **$99 Billion dollars** over 45 years.

> **[U.S. Economic Aid to Egypt:](https://www.washingtoninstitute.org/policy-analysis/us-economic-aid-egypt-designing-new-pro-growth-package)**
>
> The modern era of aid to Israel and Egypt was born following the October 1973 war and came of age with the huge sums committed in the wake of the 1978 Camp David Accords. The current levels of assistance -- to Israel, $3 billion per year ($1.8 billion for military, $1.2 billion for economic); to Egypt, $2.1 billion per year ($1.3 billion for military, $815 million for economic) -- have varied only occasionally since 1980.

**[Israel and Jordan reached a peace treaty in 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel%E2%80%93Jordan_peace_treaty)**. In 1996 - Present US aid to Jordan has been $22 Billion.  or about **1.7** Billion presently a year. Rough numbers.

Comment: Just for more context: how much of total aid from the US goes towards Israel or Palestine?